# Node function inputting undefined variables into SQL database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm sure this is a simple error in my syntax but I'm currently using a nodejs function to input into my SQL database, however, while the overall query works, and some variables get input correctly, a couple are input as undefined, which has thrown me for a loop. I'll input the query below and I presume I either added extra punctuation where not required or something.

```
    con.query("INSERT INTO _rounds(roundnum, roundse, roundtk, winner) VALUES('"+ roundnumres +"', '"+ roundse +"', '"+ roundtk +"', '"+ roundwinner +"')", function (err, result) {
    });
```

For more information, the roundnumres and the roundtk variables are the ones inserted as undefined, and are both defined by a random string generator which looks as follows:

```
    function makese(length) {
                var roundse = '';
                var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
                var charactersLength = characters.length;
                for ( var d = 0; d < length; d++ ) {
                roundse += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return roundse;
    }
var roundse = makese(20);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you could do this.  you don't have to concat strings using plus

```
const query = `INSERT INTO _rounds(roundnum, roundse, roundtk, winner) VALUES('${roundnumres}', '${roundse}, '${roundtk}', '${roundwinner}')"
con.query(query, () => {})
```